# Dealing with Database changes between version branches/rollbacks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2005, version-control

edit removed. check [Dealing with Database changes between version branches/rollbacks in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109294/dealing-with-database-changes-between-version-branches-rollbacks-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

Just off the top of my head, using stored procedures would help with this, as your pages wouldn't need to know the schema. Additionally, you update your stored procedures once, and you don't have any additional changes to make in your code (unless it's an incredibly massive schema change).